# Assign this.variable to a value does not get assigned in VueJS Axios response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, response

I am new to VueJs. I have a component called GetAllTasks in which it triggers a function that fetches the tasks Infos from the database. When there are no Tasks listed, I want to display a v-alert message.

Here is the code for my component:

```
     <template>
            <v-row>
                <v-col class="col-12">
                    <!-- The noCreatedTasks does not get assigned to True -->
                    <div>
                        <v-alert v-if="noCreatedTasks" type="error" dismissible>
                             There is no tasks created
                        </v-alert>
                    </div>   
                </v-col>
                  <v-card v-if="loading">
                    <v-card-text>
                      <v-progress-circular indeterminate class="mr-2"></v-progress-circular>
                         Task is loading.. Please wait.
                   </v-card-text>
                 </v-card>
             </v-row>  
               <!-- Rest of the view logic --> 
   </template>
   <script>
      export default {
      name: getAllTasks,  
      data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            noCreatedTasks: false   
          }
      },
     computed: {
        userId() {
            return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user')).id;
        }
      },
      methods: {
        loadTasks() {
                    this.loading = true;
                    let taskId = this.$route.params.id;
                    this.$axios
                        .get("/my-tasks/" + taskId, {
                            params: {
                                userId: this.userId
                            }
                        })                    
                        .then(response => {
                          if(response.data.tasks.length === 0) {
                              console.log("Inside");
                              this.noCreatedTasks = true;
                              console.log("Value of noCreatedTasks :" +this.noCreatedTasks); 
                           }
                           //Rest of the logic
                        }
                       .catch(err => {
                         this.error = true;
                         this.loading = false;
                    }); 
                } 
      }        
    
       beforeMount() {
                this.loadTasks();
            }
    }
 </script>
```

The problem is the `noCreatedTasks` does not get assigned to True. Note that before response the `loading` value gets assigns to true, however, the noCreatedTasks variable after the response does not get assigned to true. The noCreatedTasks remains True within the scope of Response (as seen in console.log statement). I am not understanding what makes it to set false.
The same logic of assignment works perfectly if the response is full, in other cases.
Am I doing something wrong? Sorry if the question is too basic.

The response is shown below:

```
//Response:
 {
   "id":"tid321",
   "name":"Task1",
   "owner":"Dan",
   "status":"Completed",
   "tasks":[

   ]
}
```

Note: Due to code confidentiality, I have just added part of the code which is triggering the error. There is no Syntax error seen

EDIT: These are the dependencies which I have in my `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/axios'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import moment from "moment";
import router from './router';
import {i18n} from "./plugins/vue-i18n";
```

EDIT: Similar logic code attached here: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-rhodes-l3ym1

(Used different GET request URL, but facing the same problem)

Comment: You data function should throw an error. Use commas instead of a semicolon.

Comment: @grzesiekmq the condition passes and the console log prints... > Inside.....> Value of noCreatedTasks : True

Comment: what are you doing where you have placed `//Rest of the logic`. Seeing the code you are presenting, it should work just fine. Try and reproduce the issue in for example a codesandbox.

Comment: @AJT82 Sorry I am new to this. You are right, it is easy to debug with such tools, please find the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-rhodes-l3ym1

Comment: You codesandbox was not working at all. Seems you are also using `vue-axios`? Meaning as you refer to `this.axios` in the sandbox. I excluded vuetify, as it shouldn't affect the code... I fixed the errors and it works as should. For testing I put a timeout to change the boolean value: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-swartz-cooqg

Comment: @AJT82 Thanks for your quick response, I am still getting the same error in my sandbox. Can you please explain to me how did you fix the error? Apart from the sandbox, how do I fix it in my codebase? Please provide your inputs in the answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Two things for now:

a) this seems and error

`name: getAllTasks, `, should be; `name:'getAllTasks`. But this should not be the cause of the error. What I think, considering that inside the if block the value get assigned, is that in the part: `//Rest of the logic` you are doing something that triggers this.noCreated... to go back false. Can you edit your question including that code?

Comment: @Raffobaffo Tried reproducing the above code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-rhodes-l3ym1

Comment: In the sandbox there is no logic after the if block

Comment: @Raffobaffo even without the logic, I am not able to enable `noCreatedTasks` to True, this is what I am not understanding.

Comment: I tried fixing the error as mentioned by @AJT82, but just to understand fixing in my codebase, was it the problem of axios not be used correctly?

Comment: What dependency am I missing? I have all the dependency of sandbox in my codebase as mentioned in the EDIT. Do I need to use vue-axios?

Comment: I guess the issue is that, inside the `then` function, `this` is not the current component. Do `console.log(this)` and you'll see that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. You can explicitly set what is going to be `this` inside a function using the `bind` method on a function object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Well, I figured out that the problem is with the response, but it's still weird, it works with the URL mentioned in the sandbox, but doesn't work with my URL but I see the response for my URL as shown above. Can anyone give me hint what's going on?